# SQL syntax error MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ('$fname', '$lname')

Tags: php, mariadb

```
require('config.php');
$sql = sprintf(
  "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,email,contact,pwd,isTeacher ) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", 
  $conn->real_escape_string($fname),
  $conn->real_escape_string($lname),
  $conn->real_escape_string($email),
  $conn->real_escape_string($contact), 
  $conn->real_escape_string($pwd),
  $isTeacher );
  $conn->query($sql);


//  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, contact, pwd, isTeacher) VALUES ('$fname, '$lname', '$email', '$contact, '$pwd', '$isTeacher')"; 
//    $conn->query($sql);
    if($conn=='true') { echo "Registered successfully";} 
    else{ echo "Issue entereing data" . $conn->error;  }
```

}

I am trying to add data in users table. if I add data using sprintf, it works and adds just fine. but when I add using commented out syntax, it says check MariaDb syntax to use near '$fname'. What am I doing wrong in the second syntax. why do i have to use sprintf always.

Comment: `VALUES ('$fname,` missing a quote after `$fname`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($fname, $sql);` print?

Comment: a single quote is also missing after `$contact`

Comment: the proper way of executing your quesy is to prepare the statement fist and execute with the values in an array rather than injecting your values directly in the sql statment